# Error inflating class with custom Listener

Tags: android, android-edittext, listener, android-inflate

I had to write selection Listener for EditText. When I try to launch my app, it crashes when reaches `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` with this error message:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.insymplify.user.editabletext/com.insymplify.user.editabletext.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class EditText2
```

My code:

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText2 textField;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    textField = (EditText2)findViewById(R.id.text_field);

    textField.addSelectionWatcher(new EditText2.SelectionWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onSelection(int start, int end) {
            Log.d("SELECTION", Integer.toString(start) + ":" + Integer.toString(end));
        }
    });
}

}
```

EditText2.java

```
public class EditText2 extends EditText {

private List<SelectionWatcher> mSelectionListeners;

public interface SelectionWatcher{
    void onSelection(int start, int end);
}

public void addSelectionWatcher(SelectionWatcher watcher){
    if (mSelectionListeners == null){
        mSelectionListeners = new ArrayList<SelectionWatcher>();
    }
    mSelectionListeners.add(watcher);
}

@Override
protected void onSelectionChanged(int start, int end){
    super.onSelectionChanged(start, end);

    if (mSelectionListeners != null)
        for (SelectionWatcher l : mSelectionListeners)
            l.onSelection(start, end);

}

public EditText2(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public EditText2(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public EditText2(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

}
```

XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.insymplify.user.editabletext.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:id="@+id/textView"/>

    <com.insymplify.user.utils.EditText2
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="14dp"
        android:id="@+id/text_field"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please tell me what i did wrong.

EDIT:
I have to say that it's just example (and my code works fine in this example), I'm writing code for another application right now. It has similar code, and it uses full path to class in xml. But it produces error message and I don't know why. I can't post there full code of real application. But when I delete listener from EditText2 it works fine in real app, when I add it again, I receive this error message. So only difference between working and crashing ones is my listener implementation, both uses same xml, same custom class EditText2.

Comment: Can you share the contents of your activity_main.xml ?

Comment: I see, mine was just a wild guess. anyway it's weird that it's crashing when inflating the xml if the problem is gone if you don't set the listener...?

Comment: When I delete my listener from EditText2 it works fine.

Comment: I just tried the code and it works, could you post the full stacktrace from the logcat?

Answer (score 1):

in order to inflate your custom view you need to use the full name of the class in the xml (with the package name) e.g.

```
<com.noqrax.myapp.EditText2
    android:id="...
    />
```

Comment: `in order to inflate your custom view....` - This is not 100% true. You need only do that if your widget is not using `android.widget` as package

Comment: ouh thanks, so it means that if create my custom view in package named android.widget I can use just the class name in the xml?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Of course you may be careful with class naming to avoid possible clashes with i.e. support lib provided classes, but at least you do not need to type full class names. Alternatively you can create widgets in `android.widget` that simply extends any widget you use (i.e. from others' libraries) and that will work too.

Comment: thanks that's very interesting to know, it looks much cleaner to have only the class name in the xml